# Why the size of user tables is much less that the size of other objects in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, size, postgresql-9.4

I need help in understanding my database's size. I suppose the question is kind
of simple for the database pros. I'm not a pro but I want to understand. I use
PostgreSQL. One more detail. My app is written in java and deployed in the PWS
cloud in a trial account. Maximum free database size is 20MB. That's enough for
tests and development. And now after several months of development my database's
size exceeded the limit and became about about 25MB. But from a user's
perspective (actually from my perspective) the size of my data is much less
than 25MB. So I want to find out what's taking up space.

So, here's the database structure:

```
# \d
                 List of relations
 Schema |        Name        |   Type    
--------+--------------------+----------
 public | hibernate_sequence | sequence 
 public | post               | table    
 public | site               | table    
 public | user_account       | table    
 public | user_authority     | table    
 public | userconnection     | table    
(6 rows)


# \d post
                   Table "public.post"
     Column     |            Type             | Modifiers 
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id             | bigint                      | not null
 author         | character varying(255)      | 
 content        | text                        | not null
 creation_time  | timestamp without time zone | not null
 tags           | character varying(255)      | 
 title          | text                        | not null
 url            | character varying(255)      | not null
 site_id        | bigint                      | not null
 published_date | timestamp without time zone | not null
 uri            | character varying(255)      | not null
Indexes:
    "post_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fkadd3gkkmgwsi1dy825qkfd62e" FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES site(id)


# \d site 
                  Table "public.site"
    Column    |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id           | bigint                      | not null
 last_visited | timestamp without time zone | 
 title        | text                        | 
 url          | character varying(255)      | not null
 description  | text                        | 
Indexes:
    "site_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "post" CONSTRAINT "fkadd3gkkmgwsi1dy825qkfd62e" FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES site(id)


# \d user_account
                 Table "public.user_account"
      Column       |            Type             | Modifiers 
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id                | bigint                      | not null
 email             | character varying(255)      | not null
 first_name        | character varying(255)      | 
 last_name         | character varying(255)      | 
 last_request_time | timestamp without time zone | not null
 password          | character varying(255)      | not null
 registration_time | timestamp without time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "user_account_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "uk_hl02wv5hym99ys465woijmfib" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "user_authority" CONSTRAINT "fkn48a3n0mb8d8njshjf75kgsv" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_account(id)


# \d userconnection
            Table "public.userconnection"
     Column     |          Type          | Modifiers 
----------------+------------------------+-----------
 userid         | character varying(255) | not null
 providerid     | character varying(255) | not null
 provideruserid | character varying(255) | not null
 rank           | integer                | not null
 displayname    | character varying(255) | 
 profileurl     | character varying(512) | 
 imageurl       | character varying(512) | 
 accesstoken    | character varying(512) | not null
 secret         | character varying(512) | 
 refreshtoken   | character varying(512) | 
 expiretime     | bigint                 | 
Indexes:
    "userconnection_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (userid, providerid, provideruserid)
    "userconnectionrank" UNIQUE, btree (userid, providerid, rank)


# \d user_authority
         Table "public.user_authority"
  Column   |          Type          | Modifiers 
-----------+------------------------+-----------
 authority | character varying(255) | not null
 user_id   | bigint                 | not null
Indexes:
    "user_authority_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id, authority)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fkn48a3n0mb8d8njshjf75kgsv" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_account(id)


Here's the databases's size:

    select pg_database_size('rodiahug');

    pg_database_size
    25714860
```

Here's the query I use to find out the size of my tables:

```
SELECT
   relname as "Table",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid)) as "External Size"
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;


Table                 Size              External Size
site                  64 kB             56 kB
user_account          48 kB             40 kB
post                  48 kB             24 kB
userconnection        48 kB             40 kB
user_authority        24 kB             16 kB
```

As we see adding all the sizes is much less than 24MB.

A naive google search for a query for objects' size gives the query:

```
SELECT
   relname AS objectname,
   relkind AS objecttype,
   reltuples AS "#entries", pg_size_pretty(relpages::bigint*8*1024) AS size
   FROM pg_class
   WHERE relpages >= 1 AND reltuples > 0
   ORDER BY relpages DESC;

objectname                          objecttype  #entries    size
pg_largeobject                      r           129767.0    6152 kB
pg_largeobject_metadata             r           131790.0    5704 kB
pg_shdepend_depender_index          i           71390.0     4368 kB
pg_shdepend                         r           71390.0     4296 kB
pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index   i           131790.0    2912 kB
pg_largeobject_loid_pn_index        i           129767.0    2872 kB
pg_shdepend_reference_index         i           71390.0     2576 kB
pg_database                         r           5048.0      1496 kB
pg_proc                             r           3473.0      712 kB
pg_depend                           r           11312.0     672 kB
pg_authid                           r           2921.0      448 kB
pg_attribute                        r           2573.0      376 kB
pg_depend_depender_index            i           11312.0     368 kB
pg_depend_reference_index           i           11312.0     368 kB
pg_description                      r           3876.0      272 kB
pg_proc_proname_args_nsp_index      i           3473.0      264 kB
pg_database_datname_index           i           4214.0      176 kB
pg_authid_rolname_index             i           2901.0      168 kB
pg_statistic                        r           422.0       144 kB
pg_operator                         r           907.0       136 kB
pg_attribute_relid_attnam_index     i           2573.0      136 kB
pg_database_oid_index               i           4214.0      136 kB
pg_description_o_c_o_index          i           3876.0      136 kB
pg_rewrite                          r           115.0       96 kB
pg_proc_oid_index                   i           3473.0      96 kB
pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index     i           2573.0      96 kB
pg_authid_oid_index                 i           2901.0      88 kB
pg_type                             r           416.0       80 kB
pg_collation                        r           303.0       80 kB
pg_amop                             r           1025.0      72 kB
pg_class                            r           337.0       72 kB
pg_amproc                           r           904.0       56 kB
pg_class_relname_nsp_index          i           337.0       56 kB
pg_amproc_fam_proc_index            i           904.0       48 kB
pg_operator_oprname_l_r_n_index     i           907.0       48 kB
pg_amop_opr_fam_index               i           1025.0      48 kB
pg_type_typname_nsp_index           i           416.0       48 kB
pg_amop_fam_strat_index             i           1025.0      48 kB
pg_class_tblspc_relfilenode_index   i           337.0       40 kB
pg_amop_oid_index                   i           1025.0      40 kB
pg_operator_oid_index               i           907.0       40 kB
pg_amproc_oid_index                 i           904.0       40 kB
pg_class_oid_index                  i           337.0       40 kB
pg_ts_config_map_index              i           304.0       32 kB
pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index    i           422.0       32 kB
pg_collation_name_enc_nsp_index     i           303.0       32 kB
pg_type_oid_index                   i           416.0       32 kB
pg_opclass_am_name_nsp_index        i           219.0       32 kB
pg_opclass                          r           219.0       32 kB
pg_conversion                       r           132.0       24 kB
post                                r           67.0        24 kB
pg_toast_2619                       t           15.0        24 kB
pg_index                            r           131.0       24 kB
pg_opfamily                         r           172.0       24 kB
pg_rewrite_oid_index                i           115.0       16 kB
pg_rewrite_rel_rulename_index       i           115.0       16 kB
pg_trigger_tgconstraint_index       i           8.0         16 kB
pg_trigger_tgrelid_tgname_index     i           8.0         16 kB
pg_namespace_nspname_index          i           6.0         16 kB
pg_namespace_oid_index              i           6.0         16 kB
pg_ts_config_cfgname_index          i           16.0        16 kB
pg_ts_config_oid_index              i           16.0        16 kB
pg_ts_dict_dictname_index           i           19.0        16 kB
pg_ts_dict_oid_index                i           19.0        16 kB
pg_ts_parser_prsname_index          i           1.0         16 kB
pg_ts_parser_oid_index              i           1.0         16 kB
pg_ts_template_tmplname_index       i           8.0         16 kB
pg_ts_template_oid_index            i           8.0         16 kB
pg_foreign_data_wrapper_oid_index   i           1.0         16 kB
pg_foreign_data_wrapper_name_index  i           1.0         16 kB
pg_extension_oid_index              i           24.0        16 kB
pg_range_rngtypid_index             i           6.0         16 kB
site_pkey                           i           3.0         16 kB
userconnectionrank                  i           4.0         16 kB
userconnection_pkey                 i           4.0         16 kB
pg_index_indexrelid_index           i           131.0       16 kB
pg_am_oid_index                     i           6.0         16 kB
pg_aggregate_fnoid_index            i           140.0       16 kB
pg_index_indrelid_index             i           131.0       16 kB
pg_cast_oid_index                   i           224.0       16 kB
pg_cast_source_target_index         i           224.0       16 kB
pg_conversion_default_index         i           132.0       16 kB
pg_conversion_name_nsp_index        i           132.0       16 kB
pg_conversion_oid_index             i           132.0       16 kB
pg_constraint_contypid_index        i           13.0        16 kB
pg_constraint_conrelid_index        i           13.0        16 kB
pg_collation_oid_index              i           303.0       16 kB
pg_pltemplate_name_index            i           8.0         16 kB
pg_constraint_conname_nsp_index     i           13.0        16 kB
pg_shdescription_o_c_index          i           1.0         16 kB
pg_tablespace_oid_index             i           2.0         16 kB
pg_tablespace_spcname_index         i           2.0         16 kB
pg_toast_2619_index                 i           15.0        16 kB
user_authority_pkey                 i           5.0         16 kB
pg_opfamily_am_name_nsp_index       i           172.0       16 kB
pg_opfamily_oid_index               i           172.0       16 kB
pg_opclass_oid_index                i           219.0       16 kB
pg_language_name_index              i           5.0         16 kB
pg_language_oid_index               i           5.0         16 kB
user_account_pkey                   i           3.0         16 kB
uk_hl02wv5hym99ys465woijmfib        i           3.0         16 kB
pg_cast                             r           224.0       16 kB
pg_ts_config_map                    r           304.0       16 kB
pg_extension_name_index             i           24.0        16 kB
post_pkey                           i           67.0        16 kB
pg_constraint_oid_index             i           13.0        16 kB
pg_aggregate                        r           140.0       16 kB
pg_trigger_oid_index                i           8.0         16 kB
pg_am_name_index                    i           6.0         16 kB
pg_ts_config                        r           16.0        8192 bytes
pg_am                               r           6.0         8192 bytes
pg_ts_dict                          r           19.0        8192 bytes
pg_ts_parser                        r           1.0         8192 bytes
pg_ts_template                      r           8.0         8192 bytes
pg_extension                        r           24.0        8192 bytes
pg_foreign_data_wrapper             r           1.0         8192 bytes
user_account                        r           3.0         8192 bytes
pg_range                            r           6.0         8192 bytes
pg_constraint                       r           13.0        8192 bytes
pg_tablespace                       r           2.0         8192 bytes
user_authority                      r           5.0         8192 bytes
pg_shdescription                    r           1.0         8192 bytes
site                                r           3.0         8192 bytes
pg_trigger                          r           8.0         8192 bytes
userconnection                      r           4.0         8192 bytes
pg_language                         r           5.0         8192 bytes
pg_namespace                        r           6.0         8192 bytes
pg_pltemplate                       r           8.0         8192 bytes
hibernate_sequence                  S           1.0         8192 bytes
```

And here I want to understand why these objects that take up space much more
than my user tables?
For example, these:

```
pg_largeobject                      r           129767.0    6152 kB
pg_largeobject_metadata             r           131790.0    5704 kB
pg_shdepend_depender_index          i           71390.0     4368 kB
pg_shdepend                         r           71390.0     4296 kB
pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index   i           131790.0    2912 kB
pg_largeobject_loid_pn_index        i           129767.0    2872 kB
pg_shdepend_reference_index         i           71390.0     2576 kB
pg_database                         r           5048.0      1496 kB
```

Is this normal? Should/can I do something about it?

Answer (score 0):

When's the last time you did a vacuum full? It can easily take the size down on a development DB.
Also, indexes are often larger than the data they index, the reason is because the data is aligned for speed, not space efficiency.

PG also has a collection of meta-data about your database and other "behind the scenes" tables to track things. It tracks statistics about your data like minimum and maximum values and statistics about specific often-occurring values both in your data AND postgres's meta-data/maintenance tables.

Data doesn't get really "deleted" off of your database when you delete it-- thus, the recommendation for "vacuum full". A Vacuum Full will lock down your tables and rebuild them, consolidating free space and eliminating space from previously deleted records. Tables like pg_largeobject actually stores data from "large" records in your DB, and again can be large because of previously stored data that is now deleted.

I'd do a vacuum full and see what results you get.